# Updating a doc in Alfresco, version not incremented

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, opencmis

I wrote a method that updates a doc content. It sets the stream for the new content, but the version is not incremented after calling `setContentStream` on the `Document` object.
Do I have to do it manually by retrieving existing version, then incrementing it and then setting the property `VERSION_LABEL`?

Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled auto-versioning for the content item in question?

Answer (score 0):

You should apply cm:versionable aspect before.

Comment: in order to add an aspect, you need to cast the Document to AlfrescoDocument, right? then I got an exception saying: `Type 'cm:versionable' is unknown!`

Comment: Via cmis, I think it's something like P:cm:versionable, but using the Chemistry Workbench would let you confirm that. Alternately, use the Alfresco OpenCMIS Extension, and it'll take care of a load of that for you

Answer (score 0):

In fact you have to check out first a working copy, then check in with the new content.
Something along these lines:

```
if (((DocumentType)(doc.getType())).isVersionable()) {
            Document pwc = (Document) session.getObject(doc.checkOut());
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
            ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStreamImpl(name, BigInteger.valueOf(content.length), mimeType, stream);
            pwc.checkIn(true, null, contentStream, "updated major version");
}
```